# Sample code to handle the upgrade of EVault?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Now that I have ordering EVault working, I need some help with upgrading it.
Can anyone provide some sample code (PHP preferred) that will perform an upgrade of EVault backup in SoftLayer?  If there are different input for upgrading EVault backup associated with Virtual Guest vs. Bare Metal, please provide the differences as well.

For an Endurance storage, I've used "Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Enterprise_SnapshotSpace_Upgrade" as complexType in the container, but I don't see anything for EVault listed in the SL Data Type list.  And what are other inputs that I need to specify?

Any help will be appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy

```
<?php

require_once ('/SoftLayer/SoapClient.class.php');

$apiUser = 'set me';
$key = 'set me';

$evaultId = 4862895;

$evaultClient = SoftLayer_SoapClient::getClient('SoftLayer_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault', $evaultId, $apiUser, $key);

$upgradePrice = 560;

try {

    $result = $evaultClient->upgradeVolumeCapacity($upgradePrice);
    print_r($result);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Unable to upgrade Evault: " . $e -> getMessage();
}
```

To get the price call http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItems method. The package is 0 and you need to pick out the value from "upgradeItemId" field.

Regards

Comment: Is there not a two stage process for upgrading volume capacity of EVault similar to verify then placing an order?

Comment: Nope. It is the only way

Comment: Why would I get an error like this:  "There was an error querying the SoftLayer API: Unable to upgrade the volume capacity. Cannot find item with id 80443"  As far as I can tell, the price ID 80443 is a valid for 30GB EVault.

Comment: are you sure that you picked out the value from the "upgradeItemId" field? if you picked out a price like in a new evault order that is wrong

Comment: Oh.. I must have missed the "upgradeItemId" field.. I'll make sure I get the right ID. Thanks.

Comment: OK. So it's really the "id" of the item or the "itemId" of the price that I needed to use (not the "upgradeItemId").  The example upgradePrice 560 is not for 60GB EVault, it's really 100GB EVault because I need to specify the item ID on upgradeVolumeCapacity().  At least this is how I saw it working. If it really needs to be accepting "upgradeItemId", then it's a SoftLayer's bug.  I think I've finally got all the EVault case taken care of.  Thank you all for the info!