# SoftLayer Evault verify API error

Tags: api, ibm-cloud, backup, storage, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I control the softlayer resources(Server, Storage etc) by JAVA API.

I am verifying an upgrade to the Evault storage space ( 20GB => 40GB) via the API but the API returns an error message

```
"error": "EVault service already exists for the requested location (Seoul 1).",
        "code": "SoftLayer_Exception_Public"
```

from the POST event

```
URL(POST) https://IBMxxxx:xxxxx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder.json
```

Here is the attached request body

```
{"parameters":
    [
        {"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order"
        ,"orderContainers":[
                            {"complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Storage_Backup_Evault_Vault"
                                ,"location":"1555995"
                                ,"packageId":0
                                ,"quantity":1
                                ,"virtualGuests":[
                                                    {"complexType":"SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest"
                                                        ,"id":376047
                                                    }
                                                ],
                                "useHourlyPricing":false
                                ,"prices":[
                                            {"complexType":"SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price","id":66257}
                                        ]
                            }
                            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: fixing grammar and code intentation

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing with that request is ordering an eVault storage, besides the itemId set is for a **60GB EVault Disk** capacity and not 40 Gb.

#### UPDATE

### Retrieve item prices only for eVault storage capacities.

```
https://IBMxxxx:xxxxx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,locationGroupId,item[id,keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id,name,longName]]]&objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"item": {"keyName":{"operation":"*=EVAULT"}}}}
```

---

---

Currently to perform an upgrade what you require is to use the method SoftLayer::upgradeVolumeCapacity, please see following request:

**Perform capacity upgrade to an specific eVault storage:**

```
(url POST) https://IBMxxxx:xxxxx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/eVaultId/upgradeVolumeCapacity
```

with the following request BODY:

```
 {
   "parameters":   
   [     
         559            
   ]
 }
```

Do not forget to change **eVaultId** on the request for your eVault storage, try this rest request to retrieve the specific eVault id:

**Retrieve an account's associated EVault storage volumes:**

```
https://IBMxxxx:xxxxx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getEvaultNetworkStorage?objectMask=mask[id, serviceResourceName,guestId,billingItem[id,location]]
```

Once obtained, then you may specify an upgradeItem (e.g. *"itemId": 559* that might be the *itemId* for 40 Gb evault disk).

To **retrieve the upgrade itemId's** for the different upgrade capacities allowed, use the following request:

```
https://IBMxxxx:xxxxx@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/eVaultId/getObject?objectMask=mask[id, billingItem[id, upgradeItems[prices]]]
```

(don't forget to change the eVaultId).

Review the upgradeItems property and choose the capacity required, you should use the **id** value for the capacity you need on the method upgradeVolumeCapacity.

For more information about eVaults, see below:

[Sample code to handle the upgrade of EVault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400989/sample-code-to-handle-the-upgrade-of-evault)

[How to find location of an EVault using SoftLayer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34641103/how-to-find-location-of-an-evault-using-softlayer-api)

[Sample code for ordering an EVault backup in SoftLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319257/sample-code-for-ordering-an-evault-backup-in-softlayer)

Comment: i know ORDER API(upgradeVolumeCapacity), By the way, i have used verify step before upgrade/order step. so i need to verify step. but the verify api returns error.

Comment: Currently what you can do using the portal is what you can do using the API, if you use "add" option for an eVault storage using the portal, this will display the list of available locations, once you verify/placeOrder using this, then when you try to add another you'll notest that the previous location is no longer being displayed, this is why api is displaying that error message, you require to change the location and the correct item price for that new location and capacity, for example 66975 (40 Gb)  with location 2124095 (London 1), see updated request above to retrieve that info.